# IndexError: tuple index out of range while doing prediction in tensorflow model

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, recommendation-engine

I am trying to implement deep ranking model on using listwise loss. The main reference document used is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/listwise_ranking)

I have created the model successfully but while trying to make prediction on an sample data it is giving me error as `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Below is the detailed code for creating the model

```
!pip install -q tensorflow-recommenders
!pip install -q --upgrade tensorflow-datasets
!pip install -q tensorflow-ranking


import pprint
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_ranking as tfr
import tensorflow_recommenders as tfrs
from typing import Dict, Text
import os
import tempfile
import datetime


%load_ext tensorboard


ratings = tfds.load("movielens/100k-ratings", split="train")
movies = tfds.load("movielens/100k-movies", split="train")
ratings = ratings.map(lambda x: {
    "movie_title": x["movie_title"],
    "user_id": x["user_id"],
    "user_rating": x["user_rating"],
    # "timestamp": x["timestamp"],
})
movies = movies.map(lambda x: x["movie_title"])
unique_movie_titles = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(movies.batch(1000))))
unique_user_ids = np.unique(np.concatenate(list(ratings.batch(1_000).map(
    lambda x: x["user_id"]))))


tf.random.set_seed(42)
shuffled = ratings.shuffle(100_000, seed=42, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
train = shuffled.take(80_000)
test = shuffled.skip(80_000).take(20_000)
train = tfrs.examples.movielens.sample_listwise(
    train,
    num_list_per_user=50,
    num_examples_per_list=5,
    seed=42
)
test = tfrs.examples.movielens.sample_listwise(
    test,
    num_list_per_user=1,
    num_examples_per_list=5,
    seed=42
)



class UserModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.user_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
            vocabulary=unique_user_ids, mask_token=None),
        tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_user_ids) + 1, 32),
    ])

  def call(self, inputs):
    return self.user_embedding(inputs["user_id"])




class QueryModel(tf.keras.Model):
  """Model for encoding user queries."""

  def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    """Model for encoding user queries.

    Args:
      layer_sizes:
        A list of integers where the i-th entry represents the number of units
        the i-th layer contains.
    """
    super().__init__()

    # We first use the user model for generating embeddings.
    self.embedding_model = UserModel()

    # Then construct the layers.
    self.dense_layers = tf.keras.Sequential()

    # Use the ReLU activation for all but the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[:-1]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation="relu"))

    # No activation for the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[-1:]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size))

  def call(self, inputs):
    feature_embedding = self.embedding_model(inputs)
    return self.dense_layers(feature_embedding)





class MovieModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    max_tokens = 10_000_00

    self.title_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(
          vocabulary=unique_movie_titles,mask_token=None),
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(unique_movie_titles) + 1, 32)
    ])

    self.title_vectorizer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        max_tokens=max_tokens,output_sequence_length = 4)

    self.title_text_embedding = tf.keras.Sequential([
      self.title_vectorizer,
      tf.keras.layers.Embedding(max_tokens, 32, mask_zero=True),
    ])
    self.title_vectorizer.adapt(movies)

  def call(self, titles, pool_size):
    avg_layer = tf.keras.layers.AveragePooling2D(pool_size=pool_size,strides=1,padding='valid',)
    len_titles=tf.shape(titles)[0]
    # return avg_layer(self.title_text_embedding(titles))
    return tf.concat([
        self.title_embedding(tf.reshape(titles,[len_titles,5,1])),
        avg_layer(self.title_text_embedding(tf.reshape(titles,[len_titles,5,1]))),
    ], axis=3)




class CandidateModel(tf.keras.Model):
  """Model for encoding movies."""

  def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    """Model for encoding movies.

    Args:
      layer_sizes:
        A list of integers where the i-th entry represents the number of units
        the i-th layer contains.
    """
    super().__init__()

    self.embedding_model = MovieModel()

    # Then construct the layers.
    self.dense_layers = tf.keras.Sequential()

    # Use the ReLU activation for all but the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[:-1]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation="relu"))

    # No activation for the last layer.
    for layer_size in layer_sizes[-1:]:
      self.dense_layers.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(layer_size))

  def call(self, inputs,pool_size):
    feature_embedding = self.embedding_model(inputs,pool_size)
    return self.dense_layers(feature_embedding)




class MovielensModel(tfrs.models.Model):

  def __init__(self, layer_sizes):
    super().__init__()
    self.query_model = QueryModel(layer_sizes)
    self.candidate_model = CandidateModel(layer_sizes)
    self.rating_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    ])
    self.rating_task: tf.keras.layers.Layer = tfrs.tasks.Ranking(
        loss=tfr.keras.losses.ListMLELoss(),
        metrics=[tfr.keras.metrics.NDCGMetric(name="ndcg_metric"),
                 tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
    )

  def call(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor]) -> tf.Tensor:
    self.query_embeddings = self.query_model({
        "user_id": features["user_id"],
    })
    self.movie_embeddings = self.candidate_model(features["movie_title"],pool_size=(1,4))

    list_length = features["movie_title"].shape[1]
    self.query_embeddings_repeated = tf.repeat(
        tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(self.query_embeddings, 1), 1), [list_length], axis=1)
    self.embd_concat=tf.concat([self.query_embeddings_repeated, self.movie_embeddings], 3)
    return (
        self.query_embeddings,
        self.movie_embeddings,
        self.rating_model(
            self.embd_concat
        ),
    )
  
  def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
    ratings = features.pop("user_rating")

    user_embeddings, movie_embeddings, rating_predictions = self(features)

    rating_loss = self.rating_task(
        labels=ratings,
        predictions=tf.squeeze(tf.squeeze(rating_predictions, axis=-1), axis=-1), 
    )

    return (rating_loss)




model = MovielensModel(layer_sizes=[32])
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(0.1))



cached_train = train.shuffle(100_000).batch(1000).cache()
cached_test = test.batch(4096).cache()



model_hist = model.fit(cached_train, epochs=10)
metrics = model.evaluate(cached_test, return_dict=True)
```

Now model is created, if we try to do prediction this fails

```
for x in train.take(1):
# for x in ratings.take(1):
  print(x)
  predicted_rating = model.predict({
                  "user_id": np.array(x['user_id'].numpy().decode('utf-8')),
                  "movie_title": list(map(lambda x: np.array(x.decode('utf-8')), list(x['movie_title'].numpy()))),
              "user_rating" : list(map(lambda x: np.array(x),x['user_rating'].numpy()))
          })
```

Any suggestion what could be going wrong

Below is the trace log

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-bee9a6c8ff76> in <module>()
     13                   "user_id": np.array(x['user_id'].numpy().decode('utf-8')),
     14                   "movie_title": list(map(lambda x: np.array(x.decode('utf-8')), list(x['movie_title'].numpy()))),
---> 15               "user_rating" : list(map(lambda x: np.array(x),x['user_rating'].numpy()))
     16           })
     17   # predicted_rating = model.predict({

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     65     except Exception as e:  # pylint: disable=broad-except
     66       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
---> 67       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     68     finally:
     69       del filtered_tb

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    907       else:
    908         if self._v2_behavior:
--> 909           return self._dims[key]
    910         else:
    911           return self.dims[key]

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: I don't know the exact answer but the reason why that error is occurring is because a tuple (say, tuple_1) may have only 2 elements (example) and you might have written a typo somewhere to access the second element by writing tuple_1[2] which should ideally print the 3rd element but it is showing an error because you have only 2 elements.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: updated the error trace log

Answer (score 0):

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60381499/tuple-index-out-of-range-tensorflow/60455581#60455581) finally got it resolved . Code had to be changed as below

```
for x in train.take(1):
  predicted_rating = model.predict({
                  "user_id": np.array([x['user_id'].numpy().decode('utf-8')]),
                  "movie_title": np.array([list(map(lambda y: y.decode('utf-8'),x['movie_title'].numpy()))]),
              "user_rating" : np.array([list(x['user_rating'].numpy())])
          })
```